# Matlab: How can I change specific RGB values of a picture in all three channels to "255" (white)

Tags: image, image-processing, rgb, pixel

I have a picture of size 2816x2112x3 uint8. My aim is to find all values in the blue channel which exceed 120 and change then in all three channels the RGB value to 255 so that I have white dots on the specific positions (without using a loop).

My approach is:

```
    position=find(image(:,:,3)>120); %get the positions
    image(positions)=255;
```

Unfortunately I'm stuck here as I can't use:

```
    image(positions,1)=255;
    image(positions,2)=255;
    image(positions,3)=255;
```

I also thought of doing this which I also can't use as it overwrites more values:

```
    [yy xx]=find(image(:,:,3)>120);
    image(yy,xx,1)=255;
    image(yy,xx,2)=255;
    image(yy,xx,3)=255;
```

It would be great to hear some ideas about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`sub2ind`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function converts between subscript indexing, i.e. with `x`, `y` and `z` coordinate, to [linear indexing](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html). To get the linear index of a point `(yy,xx,zz)` in a 3-dimensional array `im`, you call

```
lin = sub2ind(size(im), yy, xx, zz);
```

This also works on arrays, but `xx`, `yy` and `zz` have to be the same size, so you need to create a `zz` array with `numel(xx)` elements:

```
im(sub2ind(size(im), yy, xx, 1*ones(numel(xx),1))) = 255;
im(sub2ind(size(im), yy, xx, 2*ones(numel(xx),1))) = 255;
im(sub2ind(size(im), yy, xx, 3*ones(numel(xx),1))) = 255;
```

The complete example code:

```
im = imread('https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--pEKSmwzm--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1414228815325188681.jpg');
[yy xx] = find(im(:,:,3)>120);
im(sub2ind(size(im), yy, xx, 1*ones(numel(xx),1))) = 255;
im(sub2ind(size(im), yy, xx, 2*ones(numel(xx),1))) = 255;
im(sub2ind(size(im), yy, xx, 3*ones(numel(xx),1))) = 255;
```

creates the following output:

[image: resulting output]

PS: `image` is an in-built MATLAB function. By naming your variable `image`, you can't use that function anymore. I suggest renaming the variable.